# Как спарсить текст тега strong

Tags: php, парсер, phpquery

Как вот на этой [странице](http://rostender.info/region/voronejskaya-oblast/voronej/34153443-tender-vypolnenie-rabot-po-remontu-pomeshchenij-shkoly) используя PhpQuery спарсить информацию о заказчике (то что выделено жирным шрифтом)?

Пробовал вот так:

```
$tender_page_content->find("b-detail-table-data strong")->eq(3)->text();
```

Но почему-то я получаю значение поля "Место поставки" (г. Воронеж) вместо значения поля "Заказчик".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, что в `eq` нумерация индексов начинается с `0` поэтому `eq(3)` выдает тебе 4-й по счету `strong` в таблице с классом `b-detail-table-data`.

И ещё, перед `b-detail-table-data` должна стоять точка

```
$tender_page_content->find(".b-detail-table-data strong")->eq(3)->text();
```

Comment: так тег strong в .b-detail-table-data 3ти по счёту если считать с нуля

Comment: @evseygames, попробуй `->eq(0)->text();`

Comment: Ещё раз, в этой таблице 5 тегов `<strong>`,  тег `<strong style="display: block; max-width: 350px;">г. Воронеж</strong>` является 3-м по счёту начиная с нуля, этот текст вы и получаете в результате, как говорится, что запросили, то и получили

Comment: добавил следующий код: $tender_page_content->find(".b-detail-table-data strong")->eq(4)->text();  теперь вместо города я получил текст тега strong поля "Дата окончания приёма заявок"